# When I try rails command I get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently tried to make a new rails project and ran 'rails new new_project' command and got this error below.
Does anyone know what to do?

> /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:229:in `scan': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:229:in`block in load_config'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:105:in `filesystem_access'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:225:in`load_config'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:13:in `initialize'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler.rb:198:in`new'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler.rb:198:in `settings'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/env.rb:28:in`report'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:74:in `request_issue_report_for'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:40:in`log_error'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in`with_friendly_errors'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/exe/bundle:19:in `<main>'
>            run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
>   /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:229:in`scan': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:229:in `block in load_config'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:105:in`filesystem_access'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:225:in `load_config'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb:13:in`initialize'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler.rb:198:in `new'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler.rb:198:in`settings'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/env.rb:28:in `report'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:74:in`request_issue_report_for'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:40:in `log_error'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in`rescue in with_friendly_errors'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
>       from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.0.rc.3/exe/bundle:19:in`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [line 229](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/1-12-stable/lib/bundler/settings.rb#L229) bundler tries to load your local configuration file. It seems like that file contains a non-ascii character (an invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII).

To solve that problem open you bundler configuration file which is found at `~/.bundler/config` in your home folder and remove than invalid character.

Comment: It’s 2016. In healthy configuration `bundler` should read UTF8 without any glitch. Making `~/.bundler/config` ASCII will probably bury the problem, but not solve it.

Comment: Thank you guys. But it only says BUNDLE_BUILD__LIBV8: "--with-system-v8"
BUNDLE_BUILD__THERUBYRACER: "— –with-v8-dir" and I dont know to do exactly....

Comment: Looks like one of the dashes `—` is longer than the others. Try retyping them. Or is this just caused by stackoverflow?

Comment: It's just caused by stackoverflow. It looks okay and i have no idea where to edit. I dont think i have ever edited this file.